# Adding suboptions using optparse in Jython

Tags: java, python, jython, optparse

I am using optparse to add options to Jython script. They are like

```
$script.py -clear
$script.py -start
$script.py -stop
```

so on, now my question is how do I add suboptions to any certain option,, like

```
$script.py -start -name <name> -type <type>,
```

because there can be many options and I cannot validate or provide help by capturing all options at single level. And I found for some scripts there is options like

```
$script.py -start --help
```

-> this will give only options that can be given to parent '`start`' option. So please help me how do I achieve this

Thanks,
Chakri

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to add "sub" options. Generally a help option is done by something like `$script.py --help start` - where start is just a string option that you read and display appropriate information for.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem recently. The solution that worked for me was the following:

- as convention, use the first *argument* to represent the *command* you want
  to execute (this would be your `start`, `clear`, `stop`)
- get this command via `sys.argv[1]` (I know this is an ugly
  workaround)
- create several `optparse.OptionParser()` (one for each command)
- invoke only the `parse_args()` method of the appropriate `OptionParser`
- in case of invalid or missing command, create yet another option parser to show the usage

Here is a sample code:

```
# parse.py

import sys
import optparse

def parse_my_command_line():

    opt_parser = {}
    opt_parser['start'] = optparse.OptionParser()
    opt_parser['clear'] = optparse.OptionParser()
    opt_parser['stop']  = optparse.OptionParser()

    # Start
    opt_parser['start'].usage = 'Help for the START command'
    opt_parser['start'].add_option('--name', default = None, type = 'str',
        help = 'help for --name option', metavar = '<name>')
    opt_parser['start'].add_option('--type', default = None, type = 'str',
        help = 'help for --type option', metavar = '<type>')

    # Clear
    opt_parser['clear'].usage = 'Help for the CLEAR command'
    opt_parser['clear'].add_option('--foo', default = None, type = 'str',
        help = 'help for --foo option', metavar = '<foo>')

    # Stop
    opt_parser['stop'].usage = 'Help for the STOP command'
    opt_parser['stop'].add_option('--name', default = None, type = 'str',
        help = 'help for --name option', metavar = '<name>')
    opt_parser['stop'].add_option('--type', default = None, type = 'str',
        help = 'help for --type option', metavar = '<type>')

    # Get the command from sys.argv
    try:
        command = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        command = None

    # Get the appropriate option parser
    try:
        parser = opt_parser[command]
        # Done. Parse arguments and return.
        return parser.parse_args()
    except KeyError:
        # Invalid command. Create a parser to show default usage
        parser       = optparse.OptionParser()
        parser.usage  = '%prog [command] [options]\n\n'
        parser.usage += 'Description:\n'
        parser.usage += '  General help for %prog\n\n'
        parser.usage += 'Commands:\n'
        for cmd in ['start', 'clear', 'stop']:
            parser.usage += '  %s\n' % cmd
            parser.usage += '    %s\n\n' % opt_parser[cmd].usage
        parser.usage = parser.usage.strip()
        if command is None:
            parser.error('command cannot be empty')
        else:
            parser.error('invalid command: %s' % command)



def main():
    options, args = parse_my_command_line()
    print 'Args    = %s' % args
    print 'Options = %s' % options

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here some results:

```
[usr@localhost ~]$ python parse.py
Usage: parse.py [command] [options]

Description:
  General help for parse.py

Commands:
  start
    Help for the START command

  clear
    Help for the CLEAR command

  stop
    Help for the STOP command

parse.py: error: command cannot be empty

[usr@localhost ~]$ python parse.py start
Args    = ['start']
Options = {'type': None, 'name': None}

[usr@localhost ~]$ python parse.py stop
Args    = ['stop']
Options = {'type': None, 'name': None}

[usr@localhost ~]$ python parse.py clear
Args    = ['clear']
Options = {'foo': None}

[usr@localhost ~]$ python parse.py start --help
Usage: Help for the START command

Options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --name=<name>  help for --name option
  --type=<type>  help for --type option
[usr@localhost ~]$ python parse.py stop -- help
Args    = ['stop', 'help']
Options = {'type': None, 'name': None}

[usr@localhost ~]$ python parse.py clear --help
Usage: Help for the CLEAR command

Options:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --foo=<foo>  help for --foo option
```

Comment: **Note**: Using *optparse* is discouraged since python version 2.7. The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module. See [PEP 0389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what OptionParser is designed to handle!

Consider the following code:

```
import sys
import os

from optparse import OptionParser

__all__ = []
__version__ = 0.1
__date__ = '2014-01-21'
__updated__ = '2014-01-21'


def main(argv=None):
    '''Command line options.'''

    program_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    program_version = "v0.1"
    program_build_date = "%s" % __updated__

    program_version_string = '%%prog %s (%s)' % (program_version, program_build_date)

    program_longdesc = '''This will be displayed beneath your help information''' # optional - give further explanation about what the program does
    program_license = "Copyright 2014 Code Tester (Jython Dev Inc.)                                            \
                Licensed under the Apache License 2.0\nhttp://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"

    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv[1:]
    try:
        # setup option parser
        parser = OptionParser(version=program_version_string, epilog=program_longdesc, description=program_license)
        parser.add_option("-i", "--in", dest="infile", help="set input path [default: %default]", metavar="FILE")
        parser.add_option("-o", "--out", dest="outfile", help="set output path [default: %default]", metavar="FILE")
        parser.add_option("-d", "--debug", dest="modeDebug", action="store_true", help="Prints additional debug information")
        parser.add_option("-m", "--map", dest="listKVPs", action="append", help="Key value pair mappings (i.e. left=right)", metavar="KVP")
        parser.add_option("-r", "--role", dest="listProtectedRoles", action="append", help="Protected system roles to use (multiple allowed)", metavar="Role")
        parser.add_option("-u", "--user", dest="listProtectedUsers", action="append", help="Protected system users to be used (multiple allowed)", metavar="User")

        # set defaults
        parser.set_defaults(outfile="./out.txt", infile="./in.txt")

        # process options
        (opts, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)

        if opts.modeDebug:
            print("Running in DEBUG mode")
        if opts.infile:
            print("infile = %s" % opts.infile)
        if opts.outfile:
            print("outfile = %s" % opts.outfile)
        if opts.listKVPs:
            print("KVP's = %s" % opts.listKVPs)
        if opts.listProtectedRoles:
            print("Protected Roles = %s" % opts.listProtectedRoles)
        if opts.listProtectedUsers:
            print("Protected Users = %s" % opts.listProtectedUsers)

        '''
        Do something interesting with the parameters here!
        '''


    except Exception, e:
        indent = len(program_name) * " "
        sys.stderr.write(program_name + ": " + repr(e) + "\n")
        sys.stderr.write(indent + "  for help use --help")
        return 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

If you run this with a -h (or a --help) you get the following:

```
Usage: OptParseExample.py [options]

Copyright 2014 Code Tester (Jython Dev Inc.)
Licensed under the Apache License 2.0
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i FILE, --in=FILE    set input path [default: ./in.txt]
  -o FILE, --out=FILE   set output path [default: ./out.txt]
  -d, --debug           Prints additional debug information
  -m KVP, --map=KVP     Key value pair mappings (i.e. left=right)
  -r Role, --role=Role  Protected system roles to use (multiple allowed)
  -u User, --user=User  Protected system users to be used (multiple allowed)

This will be displayed beneath your help information
```

Now, if we run this with more parameters, i.e.:

```
testScript.py -d -i input.txt -o output.txt -m jython=cool -r Admins -r DomainAdmins
```

we get the output shown:

```
Running in DEBUG mode
infile = input.txt
outfile = output.txt
KVP's = ['jython=cool']
Protected Roles = ['Admins', 'DomainAdmins']
```

Note a few things:

- The order of the parameters on the command line is not important (as long as the parameters are supplied with their associated flags)
- The -d option in this case is used as a "store_true" parameter, to indicate that it's a Boolean flag
- The other parameters all take additional values
- If a parameter which takes a value can accept more than one value, you can declare it as a list (using the append action)
- Once all parameters have been processed, you still have any additional command line parameters available via the 'args' variable.

For more information, please take a look at http://jython.org/docs/library/optparse.html

Comment: Note - in response to shakaran (I can't reply to that comment, for some reason!) - I'm not sure that the argparse module is currently available for Jython.